# Selenium Webdriver error: An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Can someone advice me how to prevent this error: "An item with the same key has already been added."?

I have two tests that runs fine when run individually, but when I "run all" in visual studio, I get that error.

```
[Binding]
public sealed class Steps
{
    private Squish squish = new Squish();
    private Tools tools = new Tools();

    [Given(@"I navigated to the Squish homepage")]
    public void GivenINavigatedToTheSquishHomepage()
    {
        squish.NavigateToURL("Squish.com");
        ScenarioContext.Current["siteTitle"] = squish.GetPageTitle();
    }
```

Is there any alternatives to FeatureContext.Current.Add(key, value)? So I don't have to be directly be storing anything?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should read specflow documentation about parallel test runs http://specflow.org/documentation/Parallel-Execution/
It's said:

> You may not be using the static context properties
>   ScenarioContext.Current, FeatureContext.Current or
>   ScenarioStepContext.Current.

Actually your error is self-descriptive - you've created item in dictionary with key "siteTitle"

Comment: Got it! Is there any alternatives to FeatureContext.Current.Add(key, value)? So I don't have to be directly be storing anything?

Comment: You can use instance variable and use it - for your class -  [Binding]
public sealed class Steps
{
    private Squish squish = new Squish();
    private Tools tools = new Tools();
private string pageTitle;
    [Given(@"I navigated to the Squish homepage")]
    public void GivenINavigatedToTheSquishHomepage()
    {
        squish.NavigateToURL("Squish.com");
        pageTitle = squish.GetPageTitle();
    }